# If $a_0=1$, and $a_n$ is defined by $a_n=a_{n+1}+a_{n+2}$, find $a_n$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This is not a homework problem, though it is in my textbook as a practice problem that intrigues me enough to try it. I've got some idea how to solve it but I don't know how to prove my hypothesis.

The question reads exactly as follows:

> Suppose $a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots,a_n$ is a sequence of positive real numbers such that $a_0=1$ and $a_n=a_{n+1}+a_{n+2}$, $n\geq 0$. Find $a_n$.

My first idea was to find a pattern to work with. I figured out equations for the first 4 terms in the sequence:

\begin{align}
a_0&=1=a_1+a_2=(3a_4+2a_5)+(2a_4+a_5)=5a_4+3a_5\\
a_1&=a_2+a_3=(2a_4+a_5)+(a_4+a_5)=3a_4+2a_5\\
a_2&=a_3+a_4=(a_4+a_5)+a_4=2a_4+a_5\\
a_3&=a_4+a_5
\end{align}

From this, it would appear that the equation for $a_n$ is something of the form $a_n=la_{n+1}+ma_{n+2}$ for some $l,m\in\mathbb{N}$ and some $a_{n+1},a_{n+2}\in\mathbb{R}^{+}$.

Unless I'm wrong, it looks like I can deduce that $a_0$ can be written as a linear combination of two variables $x$ and $y$, and the coefficients $l$ and $m$ appear (though it is unproven) to be coprime. If this is the case, then there should exist an $x$ and $y$ to satisfy the equation $1=lx+my$... But I've only learned how to do this when $x$ and $y$ are restricted to be any value in $\mathbb{Z}$... and I'm clearly restricted to positive real numbers. So how might I be able to tackle this?

Comment: Hint: Find a recurrence relation for $a_n$ in terms of $a_{n-1}$ and $a_{n-2}$ for $n \geq 2$. Then, use strategies from here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation.

Comment: Your expression will include a constant which will depend on $a_1$ by the way

Comment: Note that it matters that $a_n$ stay positive for all $n \geq 0.$  There is not enough information to solve it if $a_n$ is only positive for $0 \leq n \leq 5,$ for example. @L.F., not really.

Comment: How come you have only one initial condition?

Comment: @WillJagy Isn't it assumed from the start that $a_n$ is positive for all $n\geq 0$?

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal That's all the book gives.

Comment: I agree with L.F. above.  Unless I'm missing something, there should be an unresolved $a_1$ in the answer.

Comment: @Doc, see the two answers. I believe I agree with the OP that $a_n$ is demanded positive for all $n \geq 0.$ So it is slightly a trick question.

Comment: @Will, seems to me that there is a tacit assumption in the solutions below that the ratio $a_{n+1}/a_n$ is constant.  I guess I don't see why that should be the case.

Comment: @Doc, not assumed, solution sequences make up a vector space of dimension two over the reals. We exhibit two basis "vectors," or sequences, I call $\lambda_1^n$ and $\lambda_2^n,$ marty calls them $c_1^n$ and $c_2^n.$

Comment: @Doc, very similar to constant coefficient differential equations of degree two. If I had a repeated root $(\lambda - \beta)^2 = 0,$ my general solution would be $B \beta^n + C n \beta^n$ for constants $B,C.$ Cute exercise to confirm that for the original problem, call it $$x_{n+2} - 2 \beta x_{n+1} + \beta^2 x_n = 0.$$

Comment: @Will.  Thanks, I can buy that  From my point of view, varying $a_1$ gives different plausable answers, but none has a nice closed form.  Truly interesting.

Comment: @Doc, I don't believe i have ever seen a discussion of the vector space aspect of this, on MSE, other than my occasional comments, still less a proof of dimension exactly two. Maybe I will go look at an ODE book.

Comment: @Will.  Great stuff.  ;-)

Comment: These answers and this discussion seems to be out of the realm of elementary number theory; I'll have to ask my professor how to solve this given that this book is about number theory. Not to say that the answers here are wrong, but it just seems to be contrary to what I'm being taught in this course.

Comment: @agent154, include my picture from here: http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/   I think I look sincere.

Comment: @WillJagy Ah I had missed the positive condition! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write it in the usual way with decreasing subscripts as $$ a_{n+2} + a_{n+1} - a_n = 0.   $$

Whatever you might want to call it is $$ \lambda^2 + \lambda - 1 = 0.   $$ If this has distinct roots then $a_n = B \lambda_1^n + C \lambda_2^n $ for real or complex constants $B,C$ depending how it turns out.

So, $$ \lambda = \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt 5}{2}, $$ or
$$  \lambda_1 = \frac{-1 + \sqrt 5}{2} \approx 0.618, \; \;   \lambda_2 = \frac{-1 - \sqrt 5}{2} \approx -1.618. $$

If the coefficient of $\lambda_2$ were nonzero, that term would eventually overwhelm the $\lambda_1$ term, resulting in (eventually) alternating negative and positive $a_n.$ We are told the $a_n$ stay positive forever. So $a_n =  B \lambda_1^n.$ Since $a_0 = 1$ we must have $$ a_n = \left( \frac{-1 + \sqrt 5}{2} \right)^n. $$

EDIT: it is easy enough to see that the set of sequences solving $a_{n+2} + a_{n+1} - a_n = 0$ make a vector space; you can add two sequences together, you can multiply by a constant, and so on. For *differential* equations, there is a fair amount involved in showing the dimension of the vector space. But we have  *difference* equations, and the dimension is exactly two, simply because knowing $a_0$ and $a_1$ completely determines the sequence. Put another way, define a basis of two sequences, call them $x,y,$ so
$$ x_0 = 1, x_1 = 0; \; \;  x_{n+2} + x_{n+1} - x_n = 0,$$
$$ y_0 = 0, y_1 = 1; \; \;  y_{n+2} + y_{n+1} - y_n = 0.$$
Therefore, if I can display two linearly  independent sequences (it suffices to check at subscripts $0,1$) then i have another basis.

TUESDAY. Note from comment above: if I had a problem with a repeated root, some constant $\beta$ and sequences solving $$  z_{n+2} - 2 \beta z_{n+1} + \beta^2 z_n = 0, $$ my characteristic equation would be $$ \lambda^2 - 2 \beta \lambda + \beta^2 = (\lambda - \beta)^2 = 0.  $$ A basis, of two sequences is $\{\beta^n, \; n \, \beta^n \}$ so that any specific solution is $$ z_n = B \, \beta^n + C \, n \, \beta^n.   $$ It's worth checking that both sequences in my basis really work!

Comment: All that is needed is to solve for B and C given the initial conditions and then show that the resulting values satisfy the recurrence. As to *how* one decides that those equations satisfy the recurrence, that is another matter. But once one does decide this, the verification is straightforward.

Comment: btw, I upvoted you since you beat me by 44 seconds.

Comment: @martycohen, fair enough. I noticed the wikipedia article goes to arbitrary degree when degree two has very few special cases when the root(s) are real. And voted back...

Answer (score 6):

$a_n=a_{n+1}+a_{n+2}$,
or
$a_{n+2} = -a_{n+1}+a_{n}$.

As usual,
let $a_n = c^n$.
Then
$c^{n+2} = -c^{n+1}+c^n$
or
$c^2 = -c+1$
or
$c^2+c=1$.

$c^2+c+1/4=5/4$
or
$(c+1/2)^4 = 5/4$
or
$c = -1/2 \pm \sqrt{5}/2
=\dfrac{-1 \pm \sqrt{5}}{2}$.

Let
$c_1 = \dfrac{-1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}$
and
$c_2 = \dfrac{-1 - \sqrt{5}}{2}$.

All solutions are of the form
$uc_1^n+vc_2^n$.
Since $a_0 = 1$,
$1 = u+v$.

Since
$|c_1| < 1$
and
$|c_2| > 1$,
for all the terms to be positive,
$c_2$ must not contribute at all,
or else there would be terms of
arbitrarily large
positive and negative values.
This means that $v = 0$.

Therefore
$u = 1$
and the series is
$a_n = c_1^n$.

Comment: Why do you know that all solutions have that form? I think it might be some well known result, but I would like to know where does this come from.

Comment: @chubakueno the solution sets of linear recurrence relations from a vector space. Here it is of dimension two as it takes only two initial terms to uniquely determine a solution. We can then take two linearly independent solutions and be sure they generate the entire space,